# Require minimal OCaml version in jbuilder package

Tags: ocaml

How do I require a specific OCaml version when defining a jbuild specification?

For instance, suppose I have this file:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(library
 ((name myjson)
  (public_name myjson)
  (synopsis "My version of json")
  (libraries (yojson))))
```

But then I want to use `Unix.unsafe_environment`, which is not available on OCaml < 4.06. How do I add this constraint to the package, so that someone trying to compile it with an older OCaml will get a nice error message (instead of the more cryptic `Error: Unbound value Unix.unsafe_environment`)?

The [jbuild specification](http://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jbuild.html) does mention the existence of variable `ocaml_version`, but I couldn't find a simple example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way to make jbuilder print a gentle message when the ocaml version is incompatible with the library.

You should be able to use `ocaml_version` in a rule stanza that produces an empty `.ml` but fail when the version is wrong. But it should be better to ask for this feature wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that at the opam level (so that this package won't be installable) by adding this to `myjson.opam`:

```
available: [ ocaml-version >= "4.06.0" ]
```

(are you sure `Unix.environment` doesn't work for you? `unsafe_environment` comes with some special precautions to be used safely)

Comment: What I actually need is to prevent the `jbuilder build` command (when trying to compile it locally, without using OPAM yet) from trying to compile the file, then failing with the cryptic error message. So the OPAM step is a bit too far.

(about the `unsafe_environment`, it was just a random example of a function having a `@since` tag)